# ISPConfig Redirection issue - How to add wildcards redirect in ISPConfig Control Panel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I have two domains xyz.nl and xyz.com .. I am trying to redirect xyz.nl to xyz.com.

It works fine if I go to xyz.nl but it doesn't redirect if I go to xyz.nl/some-url

I have managed the settings from sites --> domain (xyz.nl) --> Redirect

My Setting Are:

Redirect Type: R=301, L (Permanent Redirect + Last Rule)

Redirect Path: xyz.com

SEO Redirect: No Redirect

Can you please help how can I add a wildcard redirect so all the links redirect to xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, add this to the Apache directives of your web:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

where example.com is your domain.